# In Swift, what is the effect of having a Type Declaration after the colon?

Tags: swift, syntax, casting, nsdictionary

So basically, what's the difference between:

```
var temp1 = NSDictionary()
var temp2:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
```

they both work exactly the same.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, you're explicitly defining the type for `temp2`, saying it's an `NSDictionary`.
In the first case, you're letting the compiler infer it's an `NSDictionary`.

In your specific example, there's no difference.

However, if you do something like this:

```
var temp1 = NSArray()
var temp2: NSDictionary = NSArray()
```

the compiler will not complain about `temp1`, inferring it's an `NSArray`, while it will complain about temp2, noticing that you're trying to assign an `NSArray` to an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Swift has type inference, so in your first example the type is infered from `NSDictionary`. In your second example you manually define the type, which is not a recommended style for Swift, because in XCode you can always check a varible's type by option-clicking on it, thus there is no point in over-specifying everything and writing unneeded clutter.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it doesn't matter at all but when I do something like:

```
var a = self.returnValue()
```

I prefer to show type explicitly:

```
var a : NSValue = self.returnValue()
```

for better readability.

Comment: Having better variable names helps a lot more than specifying the type, and in fact often makes specifying the type redundant. (After all, that’s the core idea behind separating interface and implementation.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I don't mean I really give a variable name 'a'